# How to apply Spark configuration settings from R markdown document parameters

Tags: r, apache-spark, bigdata, rstudio, r-markdown

this is my first post so please be kind to me and my poor English.

I'm interested in running this [code](https://mirai-solutions.ch/news/2018/01/09/NYC-TLC-Trip-Data-Analysis-Using-Sparklyr-and-Google-BigQuery/) ([this is just the script](https://gist.github.com/lambiase/74851d17b041244995b96b9a9de824ce)). It seems that running the code without customizing it is not possible but I don't understand what I should change.

Maybe I just installed Spark badly? I'm using the latest version of RStudio, this text says this but I don't understand if the latest version is suitable.

> Please note that sparklyr version 0.7.0+ (available on GitHub, but not
>   yet released on CRAN) is needed.

I can tell you that the error occurs when it arrives in this line of code.

```
# Apply Spark configuration settings from R markdown document parameters
spark_param_names <- grep("spark.", names(params),
                          fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

the error is the following

```
 Error in shell_connection(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, app_name = app_name,  : 
              Failed to connect to Spark (SPARK_HOME is not set).
```

I'm a student and I'm not very experienced thanks for your patience

Comment: `spark_home` should direct to the Hadoop directory. The error messages say it can not find the path given.

Comment: If you are running `sparklyr` on your local machine, just removing `spark_home = spark_home` might work.